# Setting Vim options depending on file name

Tags: settings, vim

[Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/) allows you to use an external text editor for `<textarea>` and `<input type="text">` elements on websites. I use GVim for this. This functionality is very useful but drives me to a question. I frequently want to wrap the text after editing, so my workflow is as follows:

1. <kbd>CTRL+I</kbd> to launch GVim
2. Use `:set tw=72`
3. Perform my text manipulation
4. Use `gq` to re-wrap areas that require it
5. `:wq`

I would like to skip step #2 without affecting other editing in [G]Vim (i.e. I don't want to outright set `tw=72` in `.[g]vimrc` for all files). What is the best way to `:set tw=72` in this specific circumstance on Linux for example, where Pentadactyl always launches `$EDITOR` on `/tmp/pentadactyl.txt`?

Comment: Why not using `set fo+=act` for pentadactyl files then? It will autowrap/autojoin text as you type, no matter where you’ve typed it (I mean, it will autowrap the end of line even if you are typing in the middle).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an `autocmd` for this file to your .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufRead  /tmp/pentadactyl.txt  setlocal tw=72
```

This adds a hook that automatically does `setlocal tw=72` whenever you're starting to edit a buffer after reading the given filename.

See `:help autocmd` and `:help autocmd-events` for more information.

Similarly, if your step #4 is predictable, i.e. you're always reformatting the entire file, you could add an `autocmd` for `BufWrite`.